# Proving $\int^1_0\frac{\sin \pi x}{x^2+1} dx=\frac{2}{\pi(\mu_1^2+1)}=\frac{\pi}{4}\sin \pi \mu_2$ for certain $\mu_1, \mu_2 \in [0,1]$

Tags: integration, functions, trigonometry

Prove that there exist $\mu_1, \mu_2 \in [0,1]$ s.t. 
$$\int^1_0\dfrac{\sin \pi x}{x^2+1} dx=\dfrac{2}{\pi(\mu_1^2+1)}=\dfrac{\pi}{4}\sin \pi \mu_2.$$

I tried to use mean value theorem, like
$$\dfrac{\int^x_0\dfrac{\sin \pi x}{x^2+1} dx-0}{x-0}=\dfrac{\sin \pi \mu}{\mu^2+1} $$ for some $\mu \in (0,x)$, where $x<1$.

But I do not know how to go further...Any help? Thanks~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Notice that $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\sin{\pi t}\,dt} = \frac{2}{\pi}$ and $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt} = \frac{\pi}{4}$. The generalized mean value theorem states that for $f,g$ continuous on an interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that
$$(f(b)-f(a))g'(c) = (g(b)-g(a))f'(c).$$
Apply this theorem for
$$f(x) = \int\limits_{0}^{x}{\frac{\sin{\pi t}}{t^2+1}\,dt} $$
and
$$g(x) = \int\limits_{0}^{x}{\sin{\pi t}\,dt}\hspace{1cm}\text{or}\hspace{1cm}g(x) = \int\limits_{0}^{x}{\frac{1}{t^2+1}\,dt}.$$